# get request in ajax to controller action does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i am trying to do a ajax get request in asp.net mvc 3. It does not work though ie the GetSquareRoot action is not hit?

index.cshtml

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">
        http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function calculateSquareRoot(numberToCalculate) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/Home/GetSquareRoot',
                data: { number: numberToCalculate },
                success: function (data) { alert(data.result); }
            });
        }

</script>
<button onclick="calculateSquareRoot(9);">Calculate Square</button>
```

on the homecontroller:

```
public JsonResult GetSquareRoot(long number)
{
    var square = Math.Sqrt(number);
    return Json(new { result = square }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a description of your problem. How about providing info about errors, how the server responds (Firebug can be handy for this) etc.?

Comment: read the post: the action is not hit

Comment: I did read it. That edit came after my comment.

Comment: try removing the `type:'Get',`  in your ajax call

Comment: check in the firebug whether the values are posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I mount the following page on localhost:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            function calculateSquareRoot(numberToCalculate) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/GetSquareRoot',
                    data: { number: numberToCalculate },
                    success: function (data) { alert(data.result); }
                });
            }
        //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="calculateSquareRoot(9);">Calculate Square</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I hit the button, I see a request issued to:

```
http://localhost/Home/GetSquareRoot?number=9
```

Are you sure you've told us the whole story?

Comment: it was the jquery script reference even though it was showing in f12 developer tools:(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but the docs state that the type parameter should read `GET`... not `Get`

Answer (score 0):

I think your jQuery ajax is good. But I found your button tag is wrong.

AS-IS

```
<button onclick="calculateSquareRoot(9);">Calculate Square</button>
```

TO-BE

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculateSquareRoot(9);">Calculate Square</button>
```

Hope it will help you.

Luker.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the request at the developer tools(F12) at the network tab.
   see what goes out and if it goes to the right controller/action with the parameter
2. change the type of number to int instead of long(maybe the ModelBinder struggles with binding to long(not likely)
3. add an error function to the ajax call:

   ```
      $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: '/Home/GetSquareRoot',
           data: { number: numberToCalculate },
           success: function (data) { alert(data.result); },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { debugger;/*see what happened */ }
       });
   ```